# Não puxar uma informação apenas no index

Tags: php, html, css

Bom vou tentar explicar da melhor forma possivel, sei que isso pode ser simples mas ao mesmo tempo eu não sei como posso fazer isso...

Digamos que no meu Header eu tenho uma 'barra' que eu gostaria que aparecesse em todas as paginas que eu puxo o header MENOS na index por conta de um Slide que eu coloquei...

[image: Essa seria a linha]

(no caso essa barra azul eu queria que aparecesse em todas as paginas menos no index)

Solução  caso for uma div em si.

```
    <?php
var_export($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$array = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = str_replace("/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$pagina = end($array);


if ($url != 'apcefsp') {
    ?>
    <div><img src="http://localhost/apcefsp/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ficha-1.png" alt="" width="100%" height="5"/></div> 
    <?php
}
?>
```

Tem alguma maneira de puxar o header diferente ? ou algum CSS que faça tal div não aparecer exceto no index ?

Comment: Ta muito vago, posta detalhes do que realmente está ocorrendo para facilitar o entendimento...

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem para entender melhor ( a barra é uma div )

Comment: Essa barra vem de um `include()` no php ?

Comment: @Axcse Se entendi direito não é só não colocar o código Html da barra na página Index.

Comment: @Isac sim do Header

Comment: Envia o print_r($_SERVER); para que possa visualizar o que está ocorrendo aí e te mostrar o melhor caminho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desta forma você pega a pagina corrente, se for diferente da 'index.php' ele inclui o código com a barra.

```
<?php
$array = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$pagina = end($array);
if($pagina != 'index.php'){
    include 'barra.php';
}
```

Para elemento DOM como uma div:

```
<?php
$array = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$pagina = end($array);
if ($pagina != 'index.php') {
    ?>
    <div>Sua div</div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

**Explicando o código**

Pega a url corrente sem o host:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

Exemplo:

> /pagina/teste.php

Cria um array com a divisão da string que estão separadas por "/":

```
var_export(explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

Exemplo:

```
array ( 0 => '', 1 => 'pagina', 2 => 'teste.php', )
```

Pega o ultimo item do array:

```
$pagina = end($array);
```

No caso deste exemplo:

> 'teste.php'

Então ele verifica se não esta na index para mostrar a div:

```
if ($pagina != 'index.php') {
    ?>
    <div>Sua div</div>
    <?php
}
```

Para solucionar o problema foi necessário utilizar $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], já que a variável era dinâmica, mas a ideia é a mesma do exemplo acima.

Comment: Olha não entendi muito essa logica, mas eh assim  a barra tá no header.php e quero que todo o conteudo do header com um include() menos uma div especifica ( que é a com a barra ) 

Meu deus estou muito perdido huAHUSHA novato é foda por isso

Comment: Editei a resposta colocando com div no lugar do include

Comment: Fiz uma nova edição explicando o código.

Comment: Acho que to fazendo algo de errado por que mesmo assim não foi, ou ele aparece em tudo dependendo da condicional ou aparece em nada xD

Comment: Coloque o código na sua pergunta para melhor ajuda-ló

Comment: Pronto, acho que to fazendo errado hahaha

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67784/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-axcse).

Comment: Com a ajuda do Wictor solucionamos o problema. Vlw guys